# How to connect a test db to sequelize in a Github action?

Tags: docker, github, sequelize.js

I am currently starting a new project, a React website with a backend using sequelize. I would like to do things properly and implement tests and run them in a github action. However, being a student without money, I don't have a test database to run my backend tests on. So I thought I would create one on the github action using the mysql docker.
But after many tries, I couldn't connect my backend to this db and got this error:

```
          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
        errno: -3008,
        code: 'ENOTFOUND',
        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
        hostname: '127.0.0.1:32574',
        fatal: true
      },
```

In my .yml :

```
name: Vérification des tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      -master
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  frontend_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
        
      - name: Checkout du code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Installer les dépendances Node.js du front
        run: npm install
        working-directory: front
      - name: Exécuter les tests du front
        run: npm run test
        working-directory: front

  backend_test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: porte_ouverte
        ports:
        - 32574:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
    - name: Verify MySQL connection from host
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install -y mysql-client
        mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 32574 -uroot -ppassword -e "SHOW DATABASES"
    - name: Checkout du code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Installer les dépendances Node.js du back
      run: npm install
      working-directory: back
    - name: lancer le back
      env:
        NODE_ENV: test
      run: npm start
      working-directory: back
    - name: Exécuter les tests du back
      env:
        NODE_ENV: test
      run: npm run test
      working-directory: back
```

I successfully ran `mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 32574 -uroot -ppassword -e "SHOW DATABASES"` and I can see my new db. So I'm not sure if it's my sequelize config (pretty standard conf) or my understanding of docker (I tried to connect with localhost, 127.0.0.1 and db, which is the docker network created) that is the issue. Here is [my gitub repo](https://github.com/Lopidurs/LaPorteOuverteVisetoise) if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

By default a sequelize-cli create config.json without "port" like this:

```json
"test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
```

and it will use the default port (3306) if you want to change that you must add "port" like this:

```json
"test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port":"32574",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
```